# Is there any way to reference a drawable in your skin json file that will be added during runtime?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

So usually in your skin's json file you can put names of texture regions from an atlas to reference images. But what if you want to reference something that will be added only during runtime? Is there a way to specify the name of the texture region that will exist but doesn't exist at startup?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON file is being processed when creating `Skin` instance (called by the Skin's constructor) so the only way is to wait to create Skin as long as you will fulfill TextureAtlas. Of course you need to pass to the Skin this TextureAtlas instance not the `FileHandle` of *.pack/.atlas* file using

```
    Skin(FileHandle skinFile, TextureAtlas atlas)
```

version of the Skin constructor.

Another option is not to include *future* components inside JSON file but add them to the Skin by using

```
    public void add(java.lang.String name,
            java.lang.Object resource,
            java.lang.Class type)
```

after dynamically adding textures

Comment: I see, so my issue is I have 2 texture atlases - one for gameplay elements and another for UI elements. I just want to be able to access both through my skin. I am able to add the texture regions at runtime but I guess I can only access one texture atlas in the skin's JSON, not both. The other texture atlas/regions needs to be added dynamically in code. Correct me if I'm wrong.